# In fullstack why npm run build gives an error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, rollupjs

**I am getting an error while running the project. The project consists of react and express apps together.**

```
ERROR

    yarn run v1.17.3
    $ cross-env BUILD:production node index
    events.js:174
          throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^

    Error: spawn BUILD:production ENOENT
        at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
        at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
        at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:834:11)
        at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
        at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
    Emitted 'error' event at:
        at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:246:12)
        at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
        [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
        at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
    error Command failed with exit code 1.
    info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! accounts@1.0.0 start: `yarn run build && node dist/server`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Failed at the accounts@1.0.0 start script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /Users/ardaersoy/.npm/_logs/2020-04-09T08_08_06_201Z-debug.log
```

**I've tried
1)killall node and then start
2)try to change server app port number
3)delete node_modules and npm install

None of them working, please help me**

Comment: Hi there! Can you share your build script? It should be the value of `scripts.build` path in the `package.json`

Comment: I solve the error, my bad

Comment: I solve the error, my bad

Comment: Nice. Perhaps, you can post an answer so that it can be obvious to others that the issue described in the question is solved.